# Pass python string value to html form select tag

Tags: python, html

I am trying to pass python string to existing HTML select tag form. On click of a button the python string value should be passed to existing select tag in html form. For example if I have button "Update" then on-click of this button a string value should be passed.

For example, On-click of "Update", the string item "colours" should be passed to existing select tag "x".

What I have done so far:

example.html

```
<label for="x">Select values of x:</label>
<select name="x" id="x">
    <option value="">--Please select a value--</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
<center>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" name="action" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
</center>
```

example.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def dropdown():
    x = request.form.get("x")
    colours = ["Example"]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        action: str = request.form['action']
        if 'Update' in action:
            func(x)
    return render_template('example.html', x=colours)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Can anyone please let me know how to accomplish this?

PS: HTML form is not complete and needs changes to pass values from python.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this.

In the html select tag need to pass:

```
<option value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
```

But when I run the python script again, previously passed values are not shown in drop down list. I am not sure how to save passed values in html select tag form.